# How do I get the data out of this array? Single sign on

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, single-sign-on, janrain

I have implemented a Single Sign on function using Janrain. It outputs this data (amongst other data). Is it possible to break this down and extract only the displayName for example so that I may place it in a variable?

```
auth_info:
array(3) {
  ["stat"]=>
  string(2) "ok"
  ["profile"]=>
  array(10) {
    ["providerName"]=>
    string(8) "Facebook"
    ["identifier"]=>
    string(48) "removed"
    ["preferredUsername"]=>
    string(10) "OllieJones"
    ["displayName"]=>
    string(11) "Ollie Jones"
    ["name"]=>
    array(3) {
  ["formatted"]=>
  string(11) "Ollie Jones"
  ["givenName"]=>
  string(5) "Ollie"
  ["familyName"]=>
  string(5) "Jones"
}
```

Here is the script that creates it and where I would like to define the variable https://github.com/janrain/Janrain-Sample-Code/blob/master/php/rpx-token-url.php

Many Thanks

Comment: no trick question, relatively new and just wasted 3 hours of my life on this. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I've been there :D. Ok, just checking there wasn't something I was getting :). Deleted my unnecessary comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `$auth_info['profile']['displayName']`